# how to expand running process android?

Tags: android, process

help, please, how i can to expand running process in adroid? For example in my case I receive push message from GCM and show notification. I want to check on notification click whether my application is running. If running it must expand, else - run new process

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What research have you done?

Comment: I'm novice in android, because I only googled. I found the way to relaunch app on notification click, but is it not solve my problem